eslint configuration not read in my project
I have setup a project using nx and I have the following config
.eslintrc.base.json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
  "plugins": ["@nx", "unused-imports", "import"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {

        "import/no-duplicates": "warn"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nx/typescript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nx/javascript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts", "*.spec.tsx", "*.spec.js", "*.spec.jsx"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      },
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}

then .eslintrc.json
{
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts", "*.spec.tsx", "*.spec.js", "*.spec.jsx"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      },
      "rules": {}
    }
  ],
  "extends": ["./.eslintrc.base.json"]
}

then I pureposely did this in my app
import { Response } from 'express';
import { Request } from 'express';

This should trigger a warning, but nothing appear in vscode.
my setting is currently
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "always",
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": "always"
  },
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}

What am I missing ? I tried other rules they also dont work.

Stupidly simple suggestion, but if you're using vscode have you tried restarting your eslint server, i sometimes have strange behaviour in vscode and that usually does the trick. you can restart it from the command pallet.

If you have eslint 9.0.0, then the config format you provided will not work out of the box as it is deprecated. To fix this you can either:

Migrate to new flat config using the official guide. You will also need to enable eslint.experimental.useFlatConfig setting in VS Code.
Force eslint to use old-style config by setting ESLINT_USE_FLAT_CONFIG environment variable to false as is described here.
Downgrade eslint version in your project to let’s say 8.57.0.

Hope that helps!

The line with ignorePatterns in your .eslint.base.json could be the reason.
With ["**/*"] you could ignore all Files for eslint and therefore no error occurs.
I only saw this option with specific paths, so try adjusting this option with relative paths for the generated sources and config files.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There seems to a issue with ESLint not correctly detecting violations of the import/no-duplicates rule in your editor. I am assuming you have configured it properly. I can try to give you a few troubleshooting steps:

Its very important that the Ensure ESLint is installed globally or locally in your project. You can install ESLint globally or locally using npm:
npm install -g eslint

npm install --save-dev eslint


Ensure that the required ESLint plugins (@nx, unused-imports, import) are installed either globally or locally in your project. You can install them using npm:
npm install --save-dev @nx/eslint-plugin-nx eslint-plugin-unused-imports eslint-plugin-import


If ESLint is executing correctly but not detecting the import/no-duplicates violation in VSCode, check the ESLint output in your terminal. There might be additional information about why the rule is not being triggered that could help you solve this issue.

One the easiest fix problems is not having the ESLint extension installed and enabled in your VSCode editor. You can check this by going to the Extensions view, searching for "ESLint", and ensuring it is installed and enabled.

Restart VSCode Sometimes, VSCode might require a restart for changes and it might just be best to restart the VSCode application.


